Law of iterated expectation with conditional on an event
Let $Y, X$ be arbitrary random variables, and $Z_0, Z_1$ be two binary random variables with support $\{0,1\}.$
I understand two classic law of iterated expectation:
$$E[Y] = E[E(Y\mid X)] \quad \text{and}\quad E[Y\mid X] = E[E(Y\mid X, Z)\mid X]$$
Note that both are conditional on random variables.
Here is my problem:
I want to show the following is true/not true
$$
E\left[\left(1-\frac{Z_1}{P(Z_1\mid Z_0=1, X)}\right)E(Y\mid Z_0=1, X)\right]=0
$$
Here is my solving process. In step 2, I need to use law of iterated expectation. However I'm not sure because it is not one of the two classic results mentioned earlier.
\begin{align*}
& E\left[\left(1-\frac{Z_1}{P(Z_1=1\mid Z_0=1, X)}\right)E(Y\mid Z_0=1, X)\right] \\
&= E\left[ E\left\{\left(1-\frac{Z_1}{P(Z_1\mid Z_0=1, X)}\right)E(Y\mid Z_0=1, X)\big| Z_0=1, X\right\}\right]\\
&= E\left[ E(Y\mid Z_0=1, X) E\left\{\left(1-\frac{Z_1}{P(Z_1=1\mid Z_0=1, X)}\right)\big| Z_0=1, X\right\}\right]\\
&= E\left[ E(Y\mid Z_0=1, X) \left(1-\frac{E(Z_1\mid Z_0=1, X)}{P(Z_1=1\mid Z_0=1, X)}\right)\right]\\
&=0
\end{align*}
In step 2, where I apply the law of iterated expectation, is it valid to conditional on $Z_0=1$ and $X$, instead of just random variable $X$? If so, may I ask if there is any rigorous argument support this?

By $\mathsf P(Z_1\mid Z_0=1, X)$ do you mean $\mathsf P(Z_1=1\mid Z_0=1, X)$ ?

Yes, thanks for pointing it out!

Maybe helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/595566/show-that-prg-1z-1-eta-1-and-mathbbe-etaz-1-0-imply-mathbbe/595579#595579

Counterexample:
$X=Y, Z_0=Z_1, Z_0$ independent of $X$.

The law of iterated expectation builds upon the basic rule of law of total expectation, which states for any partition of the sample space $\{\mathcal{E}_1, \mathcal{E}_2, \dots, \mathcal{E}_n\}$ and a random variable $X$, we have,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{E_i}] \Pr(\mathcal{E_i}).
\end{align*}
If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, where $X$ is assumed to be discrete for simplicity,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Y] = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \mathbb{E}[Y|X = x] \Pr(X = x) = \mathbb{E}_{X} [\mathbb{E}[Y|X]].
\end{align*}
So law of iterated expectation is simply the law of total expectation corresponding to the partition generated by the events $\{X = x| x \in \mathcal{X}\}$.
In your example, if you are considering conditioning on events of the form $\{X = x, Z_0 =1\}$, note that they do not form a partition of the space. So you cannot apply the law of total expectation (and hence law of iterated expectation) directly. However, those set of events form a partition of the subspace conditioned on $Z_0 = 1$. Thus, you can apply your argument to obtain
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_{X} \left[ \left( 1 - \frac{Z_1}{\Pr(Z_1 = 1|Z_0 = 1, X)} \right) \mathbb{E}[Y|Z_0 = 1, X] \color{red}{\ \bigg| \ Z_0 = 1 }\right] = 0.
\end{align*}
You can also refer to the link in the comments for a bit more rigorous argument.
